# Keras callback for model class API

Tags: callback, deep-learning, keras, auc

I'd like to compute AUROC (Area Under ROC Curve) for every epoch and store them for later display. My model is Model API.

1. Is it possible to create a similar snippet as follow, which uses **callbacks** in case of **Sequential API**? Knowing that `self.model`, `self.validation_data` and `self.model.predict` are not callable for **Model API.**

   ```
   import keras
   from sklearn.metrics
   import roc_auc_score

   class Histories(keras.callbacks.Callback):

   def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
       self.aucs = []
       self.losses = []

   def on_train_end(self, logs={}):
       return

   def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
       return

   def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
       self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
       y_pred = self.model.predict(self.model.validation_data[0])
       self.aucs.append(roc_auc_score(self.model.validation_data[1], y_pred))
       return

   def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs={}):
       return

   def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
       return
   ```
2. Here is my main:

   ```
   histories = my_callbacks.Histories()
   history = model.fit_generator(train_gen.generate(labels, partition['train']),
                           steps_per_epoch= len(partition['train'])//args.batch_size,
                           epochs=args.nb_epochs,
                           verbose=1,
                           callbacks = [histories],
                           validation_data = test_gen.generate(labels, partition['test']),
                           validation_steps = len(partition['test'])//args.batch_size,
                           use_multiprocessing=True);
   ```

Will the AUC be computed for every batch generated by test_gen (test data generator)? What should I do to **compute AUCs on each test batch then aggregate them at the end of each epoch**?

Thank you for your help.